# GNU make fail if repo not update to date

Tags: git, makefile

How would I make a target that throws an error if you git repo isn't up to date with master (git fetch --dry-run has output)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking your requirement mostly literally:

```
up-to-date:
    [[ -z "$(git fetch --dry-run)" ]]
```

Comment: This is a bashism and I think make by default uses /bin/sh. Also won't emit if git requests a password

Comment: Well, just use `[` then.

Comment: @jpiasetz I've tested JB's suggestion with ``git push --dry-run`` because I don't have a repo where fetching needs a password. git prompted for the password as it always does, and I was able to enter it as I always do.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to do this entirely in the `makefile`. It would be somewhat easier to write a script something like this (call it `repo_is_current.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash
local_master=$(git rev-parse refs/heads/master)
remote_master=$(git ls-remote origin master | cut -f 1)
if [[ "${local_mater}" == "${remote_master}" ]]
then
  exit 0
fi
exit 1
```

Then create a `makefile` target that calls it:

```
uptodate:
        ./repo_is_current.sh
```

And make sure your main target uses this as its first prerequisite:

```
all: uptodate other targets go here
```